# Preventing pointer from pointing to nothing

Tags: c++, pointers

I am having trouble preventing objects that my pointers are pointing from being freed. I think this is the problem but I do not know how to resolve it.

My code:

```
enum TOKEN_TYPE {
    OPEN, CLOSE, TEXT
};

struct Token {
    int type;
    std::string value;
};

typedef std::vector<Token>::iterator token_it;

Tree::Tree(token_it start) {    
    root.value = start->value;
    createNode(++start, &root);
}

void Tree::createNode(token_it it, Node* parent) {
    Node current;

    current.value = it->value;
    current.parent = parent;

    if(parent != 0) {
        parent->children.push_back(&current);
    }

    ++it;
    while(it->type != TOKEN_TYPE::CLOSE && it->value != current.value) {
        if(it->type == TOKEN_TYPE::OPEN) {
            createNode(it, &current);
        }

        ++it;
    }
}
```

I tried stepping through the program and everything's perfect until the end when the program begins to exit the `createNode` calls where garbage collection frees `current` which leaves `parent` pointing to nothing; at least that is what I think is happening.

Comment: C++ has no garbage collector by default. The code is certainly not happening the way you think it does. If you want people to see what's wrong with your code quickly you need to provide something that compiles so we can try it out ourselves.

Comment: Correction: nothing _explicitly allocated_ gets deleted unless you explicitly say so. The problem here is that `current` is on the stack, and is destroyed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Then why is `Node`'s destructor being called if I'm not calling it? (Chowlett ninja answered)

Comment: the destructor of Node is getting called because it lefts its scope, as Chowlett already mentioned, you have the Node only on stack. put it on the heap by allocating it dynamically.

Comment: because Node is a local varaible to the CreateNode function, when that function ends it goes out of scope and is freed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, there's no garbage collection in C++.

Second, use smart-pointers instead of raw pointers:

```
void Tree::createNode(token_it it, SmartPtr<Node> parent)
```

Third, your assumption is right:

```
{
   Node current;
   parent->children.push_back(&current);
} //current is destroyed here
```

This happens because `current` is allocated in **automatic storage**.

If you manage memory inside `parent`, you can create the current node **dynamically**:

```
{
   Node* current = new Node;
   parent->children.push_back(current);
}
```

Comment: A) I thought garbage collection was the automatic freeing of memory that's not being used anymore? Is it something different when it automatically destroies objects that go out of scope? B) I will need to delete all the nodes inside Tree's destructor if I use `new Node`?

Comment: @Rarge: An automatic object is always destroyed when it goes out of scope, whether or not the rest of the program has a reference to it; a garbage collected object stays alive as long as there is a usable reference to it.

Comment: @Rarge B) yes, unless you take my advice and use smart pointers instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Brill, got it working, thank you :) I will read up on smart pointers now.